# Search twitter users having followers more than the input digit

Tags: c#, api, twitter, twitter-follow, tweetinvi

I am developing an .NET GUI application that links with **twitter** and I am using **tweetinvi** library to get data. I want to search people who have followers larger than the input.

**For Example:** when I input a number i.e. **2000** the program will return a list of people who have more than **2000** followers. How can I get this done? Thanks.
Below is the Screenshot
[image]

Comment: SO is nota place to ask people to code things for you.

Comment: I have tried coding this, I have searched the internet for the solution, and I didn't get any solution, that's why I posted this problem here!!!! so that if any person knows the solution he/she could help me into this.!!!

Comment: This is not a question, it's a request. Please look at how to ask a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far

Comment: **Philippe Pare** I know how to ask a question and I have got the answer.
by the way thanks for your negative comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi and I have a good knowledge of the different features provided by the Twitter REST API.

Twitter does not allow developers to search for users based on their number of followers. What you could do is to perform a simple random search and then filter.

```
var users = Search.SearchUsers("a").ToArray();
var usersWithLotsOfFollowers = users.Where(x => x.FollowersCount > 100).ToArray();
```

Comment: THankkssssss alot. YOu always come with a solution and prove an angel for me. Thanks alot This will work for me. Thanks again.